# angularjs to get the focused element on onclick

Tags: angularjs

on click on button event how to find the cursor focused input element on my form.
i have more than one input on my form, want to bind some data on onclick with the focused element.

HTML:

```
<div>
<button onclick="findFocus"></button>

<input type="text" id="name" />
<input type="text" id="email" />
<input type="text" id="address" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ng-click` (why do you have `onclick`?) and dependency inject `$event` in the template, it will give you access to it in your controller.